# Syntax for restoring SQL Server backup from non-disk source

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, restore

I have backed up and restored many a SQL Server database using T-SQL script, but always `FROM DISK` or `TO DISK`. I am not a provisioning-concerned database administrator, though, so don't have as much experience with the full range of available backup types.

Now I'm working with a database new to me where the `physical_device_name` from table `msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily` for the full backups is a GUID followed by a number, e.g. `{F1554525-23BC-48A2-89E0-4069C2D3ACF3}1`. How do I use this? Is it tape? Or a physical device name? I have searched online for references to using a GUID in restores or to restoring `FROM TAPE` and can't seem to find any examples.

Unfortunately at this moment I don't have on-demand access to the server where the backup is and the server doesn't have enough disk space for an extra copy of the database, anyway. But, when I DO get in this situation again, I'd like to know the correct syntax.

`RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM {F1554525-23BC-48A2-89E0-4069C2D3ACF3}1;` doesn't look like good syntax to me.

`RESTORE DATABASE DBName FROM TAPE = '{F1554525-23BC-48A2-89E0-4069C2D3ACF3}1';` looks more likely. Is it a tape device?

Or is there some additional set of values I need from the `backupmediafamily` table that will help me know how to write the restore statement (and a `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` statement, too)?

**Note:** the log backups look like normal filesystem files. So no issue there.

**Additional Note:** the problem with the suggested duplicate is that the answers there are less than confident. It *could* be DPM/VSS *or* tape. So... some definitive answer, here or there, would be appreciated.

Comment: My experience is that this is the footprint of a DPM backup or NTBackup.  If you are using SQL Server backups then this is a conflicting backup and will break the backup chains.  SQL Server backups should be made with one tool per database (at least) and no mix and match.  This can happen when server backups are not taking SQL Server  backup schemes into account.

Comment: @RLF There's no mixing and matching that I know of... I'm not going to be taking my own backups. If you mean that I can't restore such backups using SQL Server then okay, but you didn't really spell it out.

Comment: Sorry that I was not clearer. I did not think that you were using more than one backup method or you would not have had a question.  I intended to alert you to the possibility that some other backup process was touching your SQL Server database.  If so, you need to find that process and have it exclude your SQL Server databases.  (These other processes are not evil, but if they sporadically backup databases they are breaking the restore chain. If you used DPM (for example) exclusively then you would use the DPM tools for backups and restores and would not be using standard SQL backups.)

Comment: @ErikE Is this virtual server ? Also can you find out what the `logical_device_name` is for the one that shows GUID using `SELECT a.physical_device_name
 ,a.logical_device_name
 ,b.backup_set_uuid
 ,a.device_type
 ,b.backup_start_date
 ,b.backup_finish_date
FROM msdb..backupmediafamily a
INNER JOIN msdb..backupset b ON a.media_set_id = b.media_set_id` + anything logged into Windows Event logs ?

Comment: @Kin It is a virtual server--but I'm confused because a few weeks ago it wasn't a virtual server and I saw the same GUID style for backup.